# Click item in listview always selects item at index 0

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

This is the main part of my code section where I made some changes at the bottom of the code but the problem occurs when I select an item in listview..

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

How can I solve this please?

```
public class DisplayWishesActivity extends Activity {
private DatabaseHandler dba;
private ArrayList<MyWish> dbWishes = new ArrayList<>();
private WishAdapter wishAdapter;
 ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_wishes);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    refreshData();
}

private void refreshData() {
    dbWishes.clear();
    dba = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    ArrayList<MyWish> wishesFromDB = dba.getWishes();

    for (int i = 0; i < wishesFromDB.size(); i++){
        String title = wishesFromDB.get(i).getTitle();
        String dateText = wishesFromDB.get(i).getRecordDate();
        String content = wishesFromDB.get(i).getContent();
        int mid = wishesFromDB.get(i).getItemId();

        MyWish myWish = new MyWish();
        myWish.setTitle(title);
        myWish.setContent(content);
        myWish.setRecordDate(dateText);
        myWish.setItemId(mid);
        dbWishes.add(myWish);
    }
    dba.close();

    //setup adapter
    wishAdapter = new WishAdapter(DisplayWishesActivity.this, R.layout.wish_row, dbWishes);
    listView.setAdapter(wishAdapter);

    wishAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class WishAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyWish>{
    Activity activity;
    int layoutResource;
    MyWish wish;
    ArrayList<MyWish> mData = new ArrayList<>();

    public WishAdapter(Activity act, int resource, ArrayList<MyWish> data) {
        super(act, resource, data);
        activity = act;
        layoutResource = resource;
        mData = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public MyWish getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition(MyWish item) {
        return super.getPosition(item);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if ( row == null || (row.getTag()) == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);

            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

           holder.mTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.mDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dateText);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        holder.myWish = getItem(position);

        holder.mTitle.setText(holder.myWish.getTitle());
        holder.mDate.setText(holder.myWish.getRecordDate());

        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
       //  int mypos = position;
     //  holder.mTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


               String text = finalHolder.myWish.getContent().toString();
               String dateText = finalHolder.myWish.getRecordDate().toString();
               String title = finalHolder.myWish.getTitle().toString();

               int mid = finalHolder.myWish.getItemId();

               // Log.v("MyId: " , String.valueOf(mid));
               Intent i = new Intent(DisplayWishesActivity.this, WishDetailActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("content", text);
                i.putExtra("date", dateText);
                i.putExtra("title", title);
                i.putExtra("id", mid);

                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        return row;

    }

    class ViewHolder{

        MyWish myWish;
        TextView mTitle;
        int mId;
        TextView mContent;
        TextView mDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your itemclicklistener out of your adapter class and use the position variable from the onItemClick to get the MyWish Object at that index and then access the getContent,getRecordDate functions through that object

Comment: Uh Sir can you modify the code for me if you don't mind.

Comment: Have a look here for an example https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/